# Could someone look over were I went wrong in my code?

Tags: c++

I'm doing another coding exercise and my code is not giving me correct answers.

For example:

What was the total amount of milk produced in the morning: 3590.56

- Number of cartons = 949 supposed to be 950
- Cost of producing = 1364.41 correct
- Profit of producing = 256.47 supposed to be 256.5

Below is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

const double CARTON = 3.78;
const double PRODUCECOST = 0.38;
const double PROFIT = 0.27;

int main() {
    double milkProduced, numCartons;
    double costOfProducing, profitOfProducing;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    cout << "What was the total amount of milk produced in the morning: " << endl;
    cin >> milkProduced;

    numCartons = milkProduced / CARTON;
    costOfProducing = milkProduced * PRODUCECOST;
    profitOfProducing = numCartons * PROFIT;

    cout << static_cast<int>(numCartons) << endl;
    cout << costOfProducing << endl;
    cout << profitOfProducing << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to post code? The reason why I posted a link is because I don't know how to post the entirety of it without doing samples. Is there a faster way? Copy and pasting it makes the code look weird.

Comment: Darunia, you can just copy the code in (making sure there's a blank line before it), select it with mouse or arrow keys, and press CTRL-K. That indents the selected text by 4 spaces, which is what makes it look like a code block (I basically did that when I copied your code to on-site).

Answer (score 2):

That's very close, but your `num_cartons` value is actually `949.883...` and, when you cast that to an `int`, it truncates the fractional part rather than rounding it.

In addition, you only do that for the *output* and do not feed that change back into the variable for the subsequent calculations (specifically, the profit).

I suggest, rather than doing that, you try:

```
numCartons = round(milkProduced / CARTON); // needs <cmath>
```

to set the value.

That will make the number of cartons an integral value, or close enough for classwork assignments. In other words:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

const double CARTON = 3.78;
const double PRODUCECOST = 0.38;
const double PROFIT = 0.27;

int main() {
    double milkProduced, numCartons;
    double costOfProducing, profitOfProducing;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    cout << "What was the total amount of milk produced in the morning: " << endl;
    cin >> milkProduced;

    numCartons = round(milkProduced / CARTON);
    costOfProducing = milkProduced * PRODUCECOST;
    profitOfProducing = numCartons * PROFIT;

    cout << numCartons << endl;
    cout << costOfProducing << endl;
    cout << profitOfProducing << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is more in line with what you expect:

```
> ./testProg
What was the total amount of milk produced in the morning: 3590.56
950.00
1364.41
256.50
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, you possibly *should* be truncating rather than rounding down, since you can most likely not sell a partially filled container (or add water if you're, shall we say, ethically ambiguous).

However, even if that is the case, you should *modify* the variable so that it affects the profit figure, rather than just outputting the rounded value and using the original.

I've only rounded since you stated that `950` was the correct carton count.

Comment: @John, just add 0.117 cartons of water across a selection of containers, they'll never know :-)

Comment: I would never do that, I believe in quality food and truth in advertising!

Comment: That was said in jest, @John, but adding 0.1% of water to a substance that's *already* more than 80% water would hardly be a quality issue. In any case, this is an educational exercise with an apparently specific required answer, and academia is rarely compatible with reality :-) You're probably right but it's not really that relevant to the question. Regardless, I'll add an addendum just to be safe.